# No Ethernet after installation on Ubuntu 20.04 (drivers r8169 installed)

Tags: networking, 20.04, uefi, ethernet

I have installed Ubuntu on PC with Windows, but made it boot only via BIOS.

But I don't have any Ethernet connection, though it seems like it had on installation. (EDIT: nope, didnt have ethernet on installation either)

It seems like Realtek drivers are installed. I have alredy tried to restart network manager, but it didnt help.

UEFI Ubuntu, motherboard: MSI z490 A-Pro

Comment: Do you have access to the `lshw` command? Can you get a list of the hardware with IDs?

Comment: Yes I have access, unfortunately i cant get list from ubuntu pc to there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, seems like, all I had to do is - to install Kernel 5.9 and after that to reboot PC with ubuntu. Now I have an ethernet, amen. Damn these ubuntu developers, who didnt put kernel 5.9 on ubuntu installation image.

Minor guide for future fellas:

1. Download 4 Kernel files from Kernel site, (1 all headers, 3 either **generic** or **lowlatency**)
2. Put them on usb (or whatever, main goal to **transfer** them to ubuntu pc)
3. Put these 4 kernel files into some directory on ubuntu, and use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install them
4. Kernel 5.9 is installed. Reboot PC.
5. ???
6. PROFIT! You have now an ethernet access.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cli command to install kernel 5.9,
I got this form [this source](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/10/linux-kernel-5-9-released/)

```
cd /tmp/

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_all.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-modules-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```